# The relationship of yaw and roll on a spacecraft using Trust Vector Control

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, aircraft, propulsion

I’ve previously asked the question how does applying rudder (yaw) on aircraft also cause roll. Turns out it’s caused by both the rudder usually being above or below the center of mass and the differential in lift between both wings. I’m now wondering if this same “principle” if you will of yaw creating some sort of "roll" as a secondary effect, could also occur on a spacecraft using TVC (not RCS) as the primary flight controls during the powered stage of flight (while in space)? Reason I'm asking is that I've played a good deal of KSP and I’ve noticed that when I’ve applied yaw while steering using gimbaling there’s a small amount of roll that goes with it. Obviously the flight controls and environment are very different from a traditional aircraft but at the end of he day it’s the same good ole concept of applying an unbalanced torque.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your question to spell out acronyms. If "TVC" is "thrust vector control," there is also (v1) a typo in the question title.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for a spacecraft using TVC to experience roll as a secondary effect of yaw, due to the unbalanced torque generated by the TVC system. The exact amount of roll experienced would depend on factors such as the spacecraft's mass distribution, the design of the TVC system, and the thrust vector orientation. However, it is important to note that in microgravity environments, the effects of roll may be different compared to traditional aircraft due to the absence of an atmosphere and the different forces and dynamics involved in spacecraft flight.